# Shouldn't the query optimizer still choose a hash join when I add a new index?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, hints

I had this query

```
SELECT Equipment.EquipmentId, ServiceStartDate FROM Service, Equipment 
WHERE Service.EquipmentId = Equipment.EquipmentId 
AND Vendor LIKE 'VEND: 1' AND ServiceType = 'failure';
```

Feature this plan:
[image]

Notice, it uses a hash join for the join field. And the total cost is 20, with time being 4.

Then, I added an index on EquipmentId the table using it as a foreign key (Service).

```
CREATE INDEX service_equipid2 ON Service(EquipmentId)
```

The same query produced this plan:
[image]
Which has a total cost of 22, with time being 6.

Shouldn't it have still selected the former plan?

(When I use a hint,

```
SELECT /*+NO_INDEX(SERVICE)*/ Equipment.EquipmentId, ServiceStartDate 
FROM Service, Equipment 
WHERE Service.EquipmentId = Equipment.EquipmentId AND Vendor LIKE 'VEND: 1' 
AND ServiceType = 'failure';
```

it returns to the first result).

Comment: The estimated cost for the first explain is "7".  The estimated cost for the second is "6".  The SQL engine uses the plan with the minimum cost, so what is your question?  If you disagree with the costs, it is possible that some statistics were updated when you created the index.

Comment: wow, I think then, I did not understand cost.  I guess it's not the sum of all the costs listex?

Comment: . . Gosh, I hadn't thought of that.  Usually, the costs are for the "entire" statement.  That is, they are inclusive of everything below them in the tree.  I admit, though, that Oracle documentation is not particularly clear on this point (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/ex_plan.htm#autoId13).

Comment: It's a bit difficult to work out with that presentation of the explain plan -- The regular DBMS_Xplan version which shows the levels is easier to follow, and to see that the costs are cumulative.

Comment: I just did the explain plan like @DavidAldridge suggested, now, I get completely different results. :|

Comment: The optimiser is a fickle mistress, my friend.